# DisplayMemberPath gives an error when I try to use it to display the value of my dictionary in a Combo Box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, windows-8.1

Here is my Combo Box

```
<ComboBox Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="comboBox1" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="25">
        </ComboBox>
```

Here is my C# code

```
var source = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        source.Add("Item1", 0.4);
        source.Add("Item2", 0.3);
        source.Add("Item3", 0.1);
        source.Add("Item4", 0.1);

        var formateDSource = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            formateDSource.Add(string.Format("[{0}, {1}]", item.Key, item.Value), item.Key);
        }

        comboBox1.ItemsSource = source.Values;
        comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
```

When I run my code I don't see anything in the Combo Box. What have I done wrong?

Comment: try . instead of Value

Comment: Change the itemssource code comboBox1.ItemsSource = source;

Comment: @user3929914 in your case either set `ItemsSource` to `source` or don't set `DisplayMemberPath` at all

Comment: having the ItemSource to Source shows both key and value in my Combobox. I just want top see the values so my Combo Box should show me Item1, item2,item3,item4 not each item and the key. Why does nobody get this

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<ComboBox Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value" x:Name="comboBox1" FontSize="25"/>

var source = new Dictionary<string, double>();
            source.Add("Item1", 0.4);
            source.Add("Item2", 0.3);
            source.Add("Item3", 0.1);
            source.Add("Item4", 0.1);

            var formateDSource = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                formateDSource.Add(string.Format("[{0}, {1}]", item.Key, item.Value), item.Key);
            }

            comboBox1.ItemsSource = source;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me as when I run your code I get an error. but as soon as I remove the DisplayMemberPath="Value" it works but it shows me both key and value. But I need it to show just value

Answer (score -1):

you should try '.' instead of Value, it should pick it up as binding to the object as it has no property name

```
comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = ".";
```

Comment: This did nothing for me but give an error saying it does not accept chars just strings so I change it to "." and nothing happened

Comment: Making a change like I did above (see added code) works for me. no issues

Comment: Please tell me if this works for you in wpf or windows store apps or both because I want it to work for windows store apps

Comment: that's wpf, couldn't find win apps anywhere in question sorry.... but "." works in wpf .. I use it all the time